# Cannot find unity-tweak-tool in Software Centre

Tags: unity, 16.04, software-center

I installed the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 16.04 in my Lenovo g565 laptop but there are software missing in Software Center. 
These include the vital ones that is the `unity-tweak-tool`, `rawtherapee`, many games etc.

I re-installed the 64bit version but the problem is same. Is this something normal or do I have a problem of hardware or a bug in the system?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

Comment: @ThanosApostolou youre confusing `unity-tweak-tool` which is actively maintained with `ubuntu-tweak` which is not longer maintained.

Comment: Sorry for mistake I delete comment

Answer (score 1):

I am also running Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and confirm that both applications you mention appear in Software Centre on my system.

The problem could possibly be your software sources. Check the "Software & Updates" screen within "System Settings". The picture below shows how mine currently looks. I believe "Universe" would be required for Unity Tweak Tool.

[image: Software & Updates]

It would also be worth checking the server in the "Download from" drop down. If you select "other", you can test for the best server.

Hope that helps.